# "method .. overrides nothing" error when using overloaded method in abstract parent

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and can't find a way to achieve what I want.
I want to have abstract method in parent class like this

```
def copy():M
```

and then in each child class this method should have different number of arguments like

```
def copy(id: Int, title: String):M
```

Now when I try

```
override def copy(id: Int, title: String):M
```

I've got compilation error

> method copy overrides nothing

Comment: Yes, Scala *does* support method overloading. (Try to narrow in the titles; although this still a bit misleading.)

Comment: No you can't do this - how would you expect this to work: `val o: Base = new Derived(); o.copy()`? You could parameterise the base class by the parameters required by the `copy` function e.g. `class Base[P] { def copy(params: P): M }`

Comment: "*in each child class this method should have different number of arguments*" sounds like an incredibly bad idea. That's not [how subclasses work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Well. Abstract parent class doesn't used on it's own any way?  May be this should be a trait and not base class. I just want to be sure every child have this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parameters would be of the same type, you could write method signature like this

```
def copy(args: SomeType*):M
```

If not, you can use abstract type

```
trait T { 
  type CopyParam
  def copy(c: CopyParam): T 
}

case class SomeCopyParam(i: Int, s: String)

class A extends T { 
  type CopyParam = SomeCopyParam 
  def copy(c: SomeCopyParam): A = {
   println(c.i + c.s)
   this // some changed copy should be here
  } 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val original = new A()
val copy = original.copy(SomeCopyParam(1, "a"))
```

Comment: Can you please show how it can be used? Should I create new FirstCopyParam object and then pass it to copy function?

Comment: Yes, just like you said. Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is working solution to problem. It is pity so it is not possible to pass number of variables directly to copy function to create this SomeCopyParam inside it on the fly